# Set Cursor Edittext in Center - Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor

I already tryed `center_vertical|top`, `fill_vertical`, `center|start`, but cursor still standing in top.

What I got:

[image: What I got]

What I want:

[image]

EDIT: I set android:paddingBottom="0sp" and worked!

Comment: Could you post your xml for the EditText. I was curious when I read this question. I tried using an EditText and the hint is always at the center without specifying the gravity or any other parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
android:paddingTop="20sp"
android:paddingBottom="20sp"
android:textAlignment = "center"
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the gravity to the center_vertical. Are you sure you are setting the gravity , not the layout gravity?

Comment: Yes. android:gravity="center_vertical"

Comment: Can you please post the Code here?

Comment: I already got it, but here is the code:

        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:hint="Search a like..."
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"